# Module is imported, but is still rendering NameError

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python packages and I am in process of learning how organize code into packages.
I tried out a small program for testing purpose and I am curious about an error that I encountered.

I have put the following package-structure (I am currently working with `regular packages` only as I don't have a good understanding of `namespace packages`):

```
parent/
    main.py
    p1/
        __init__.py
```

The code in `p1/__init__.py` is as follows:

```
import math
print('p1 imported.')
```

The code in `main.py` is as follows:

```
from p1 import math

def main():
    print(p1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The output that it gives me is as follows:

```
path-to-parent>python3 main.py
p1 imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 8, in main
    print(p1)
NameError: name 'p1' is not defined
```

I understand that it has imported math from `sys.modules` or the subsequent full search that it must have performed after encountering the `import math` statement in `p1/__init__.py`. It also executed the subsequent statement `print('p1 imported')` indicating that the module `p1` has been imported. Then why does the `NameError` pop up?

With my reading of [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), my guess is that although the module `p1` has been imported, it has not undergone the binding process because of the way it has been imported: `from p1 import math`.

I would still need help to understand this.

> NOTE: I am using `Anaconda Python 3.7.3` on windows 10 (64bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from p1 import math

def main():
    print(p1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

`p1` here is the name of the directory, it is not a python variable that can be used.

It is very roughly analogous to the following attempt:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    print(filename)
```

Which will obviously raise `NameError` because `filename` is not defined.

Perhaps a better example is this:

```
from math import pi

print(math)
```

This also raises `NameError` because `math` is never defined as a variable that can be used outside of the `import` mechanism. `math` here is the name of the module from which `pi` is imported, but it can only be seen by the import mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.
Also do you mean that this error has got nothing to do with the importing process? As in `p1` has been successfully imported right?

Comment: @TejasKhajanchee correct. `p1` is imported, it just can't/shouldn't be used like you tried

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to demonstrate why what you're doing fails:

```
>>> from math import sin
>>> sin
<built-in function sin>
>>> math
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

The point is, that `math.sin` is imported as `sin`, but the `math` module that is needed for this is not stored for reference anywhere. For that reason, there is no local `math` object you could refer to.

If you want to refer to the `math` module as a whole, just import it as a whole. For your example, just `import p1`.